# C++ Class & .H Sorting

Tags: c++

Good evening experts and gurus !!

I have an array object that record the following..

This is at **record.h**

```
Class Record
{
private:
string name;
int data;
float valueData;
public:
bool operator<(const Record&) const;
}
```

and the constructor are created at **record.cpp**

record.cpp i added this

```
bool Record::operator<(const Record& rhs) const
{
return valueData < rhs.valueData;
}
```

At main.cpp I created record Array of Size 10

```
#include "record.h"

Record rec[10];
```

I did

```
sort(&rec[0], &rec[2]);
```

**but nothing seems changing or sorted**.. i got 3 element , rec[0], rec[1], rec[2] and i want sort them ,but they are of another header file record.h & its record.cpp which describe above.

**Original Question**
Next is  i recorded several value to the object

and now rec got 3 index

```
rec[0]
name = "jack1"
data = 1
valueData = 20

rec[1]
name = "jack2"
data = 2
valueData = 15

rec[2]
name = "jack3"
data = 3
valueData = 25
```

What i want to achieve is do a sort that can rearrange this array by **valueData** highest ascending form so.. it will be

`rec[2]` then `rec[0]` then `rec[1]` ..

but i wanna sort by class array object. and re-arrange the value together , how do i achieve this.

the 3 value is private, so i not sure where do i create the sort function, at main.cpp or at record.cpp , next is how do i sort it so it can output in the way below..

```
-- Highest to lowest --
1) Name: Jack3, Data = 3, Value =25
2) Name: Jack1 , Data =1 , Value = 20
3) Name: Jack2, Data = 2, Value = 15
```

**Thanks for all help and guide!!**

Comment: Define a comparison function implementing a strict weak order on your `Record` type (e.g., using `bool operator< (Record const&, Record const&)`) and then use `std::sort()`.

Comment: how do i do it... sorry really new here

Comment: You posted this same question a few hours ago... what were wrong with the answers there?

Comment: I really dont get it .. i mean i try to use the solution provided. but i still cant get it right, i refined the question so it be more clear what i really asking.. i know i have to use sort algorithm standard library, but the issue is how do i use it with the situation i am in, normally sort is use for int array that is within the class, and not bound by private or other .h .cpp etc.

Comment: Do what? Define a strict weak order? Well, the axioms can easily be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_order). I would probably implement a member function (say `compare()`) which does the actual comparison and call this from my `operator<()`. ... and then I'd call `std::sort()`. Of course, the exercise is to look all these bits of information up and figure out how the source looks like. I could write this for you but I don't think I need this kind of exercises.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct:  `record rec[10];`  it should be `Record rec[10];`

Comment: sorry typo error here. it is Record rec[10] on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::sort` in conjunction with something that compares two `Record`s.  There are at least 3 ways to provide this compoarison.

1: Implement an `operator<` on `Record`:

```
class Record
{
public:
  bool operator<(const Record& rhs) const
  {
    return valueData < rhs.valurData;
  }
};
```

...then:

```
sort(&rec[0], &rec[10]);
```

2: Provide a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object):

```
struct compare_records : public std::binary_function<bool, Record, Record>
{
  bool operator()(const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) const
  { 
    return lhs.valueData < rhs.valueData;
  }
};
```

...then:

```
sort_if(&rec[0], &rec[10], compare_records());
```

3: (If you have a C++11 compiler) Use a lambda:

```
sort_if(&rec[0], &rec[10], [](const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) -> bool
{
  return lhs.vaklueData < rhs.valueData;
});
```

EDIT:

Here is a complete sample that shows how to use the first method:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Record
{
public:
    string name;
    int data;
    float valueData;
public:
    bool operator<(const Record& rhs) const
    {
        return valueData < rhs.valueData;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Record rec[10];
    rec[0].name = "jack1";
    rec[0].data = 1;
    rec[0].valueData = 20;

    rec[1].name = "jack2";
    rec[1].data = 2;
    rec[1].valueData = 15;

    rec[2].name = "jack3";
    rec[2].data = 3;
    rec[2].valueData = 25;

    sort(&rec[0], &rec[3]);

    bool bk = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your sort method, but nothing seem sorted on my end.. still remain same for the position of the array.

Comment: hi there, its working now. but its sort from ascending manner. how do i make it sort by descending

Comment: @user1726440:  Change the code in operator<.  Whatever code you wirite in operator< is what defines strict weak ordering.

Comment: thanks. can work , i change the function to valueData > rhs.ValueData and its work.

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
sort(&rec[0], &rec[3]);
```

You were only sorting the 1st two elements, because the 2nd iterator in a range defined by an iterator pair by convention always points *one past* the end of the range you want to operate on.